# Create properties in a class with the names and values of all the variables passed to the constructor

Tags: php, class, variables, properties, construct

I want to create properties in a class with the names of all of the variables passed to the constructor and with the same values.

I was able to do it with strings:

```
class test {

    public function __construct() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach($args as $arg) {
            $this->{$arg} = $arg;
            $this->init();
        }
    }

    public function init() {
        echo $this->one;
    }
}

// Output: "one"
$obj  = new test("one");
```

But I don't know how I can do it with variables. I tried this:

```
class test {

    public function __construct() {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach($args as $arg) {
            $this->{$arg} = $arg;
            $this->init();
        }
    }

    public function init() {
        echo $this->one;
    }
}

$one  = "one!";
$obj  = new test($one);
```

Output:

```
Notice: Undefined property: test::$one on line 13
```

What I wanted it to output:

```
one!
```

Comment: You really want a property called `one!`? With the exclamation mark?

Comment: A property called "one" with the value "one!".

Comment: So you need to do something to remove the `!`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function init() {
   echo $this->{'one!'};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in any sane way to get the name of a variable used in calling code inside the callee. The sanest method is to use `new test(compact('one'))`, which gives you a regular key-value array inside `test::__construct`, which you can loop through.

http://php.net/compact